# building a teleoperated robot

Tags: ros, wireless, nxt, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I would like to build a low-cost robot, preferably from the NXT kit or cheaper. I would like to run ROS on my workstation such that it controls the robot by sending commands to some kind of wireless interface on the robot and receiving sensory data - this way I don't have to buy a separate netbook or something to install into the robot and at the same time, run some pretty CPU-intensive algorithms. I was wondering if such a setup is possible.

If the above is possible, is there any reason why I should get a turtlebot instead of an NXT if both offer driving capabilities and the "robot brains" does not have to be physically connected to the machine?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27480/building-a-teleoperated-robot/) by [ejang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1781/ejang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can control NXT by bluetooth. You can use stack http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT with standart firmware NXT or own stack like http://code.google.com/p/lego-nxt-car-like/ with LeJos firware

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2012-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0